# From blog golang arrays slices and strings

Tags: go

```
type path []byte

func (p path) ToUpper() {
    for i, b := range p {
        if 'a' <= b && b <= 'z' {
            p[i] = b + 'A' - 'a'
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    pathName := path("/usr/bin/tso")
    pathName.ToUpper()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", pathName)
}
```

[Exercise: Convert the ToUpper method to use a pointer receiver and see if its behavior changes.]
how to use a pointer method ? i have tried to dereference *p and tried to delete i from range but it keeps saying mismatched types.

Comment: func(p *path) { ... (*p)[i] = ... }

Answer (score 1):

Since `path` is a type defined on a `[]byte` which happens to be a slice, there is no need to use a pointer receiver since slice types are already reference types.

However, if a pointer receiver is required, you'll need to dereference the pointer value everywhere in your method to get the underlying slice value:

```
func (p *path) ToUpper() {
    for i, b := range *p { // dereference p with a * to get the
                           // underlying []byte slice
        if 'a' <= b && b <= 'z' {
            (*p)[i] = b + 'A' - 'a' // derefernce p here as well
        }
    }
}
```

Working code: https://play.golang.org/p/feqeAlb80z

Comment: i was running it in the sandbox so it tells me. tmp/sandbox605541423/main.go:21: invalid operation: p[i] (type *path does not support indexing)

Comment: @abhnik one question why we're dereferencing (*p) using parentheses ?

Comment: That is because of operator precedence. The indexing operator `[]` have a higher precedence than dereference operator `*`. So without the parentheses, `*p[i]` will try to index `p` directly, which is a pointer type value and does not support indexing. With parentheses, `p` is dereferenced first through application of `*` and then the resultant value, which is a slice, is indexed by the `[]`. This is also the reason you were getting the *(type *path does not support indexing)* error.